# scroll not appear after ajax call fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullpage.js, slimscroll

I'm using ajax with [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) to get gallery images and apply isotope on it, after I click on the link to open gallery (go to target section) the scroll of the page does not appear and I can't scroll, but if I re-size the browser the scroll appears ..

/* HTML */

```
<div class="section" id="textscroll">
    <div class="s" data-anchor="stext">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ajax_content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

/* JS */

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['home', 'about', 'gallery'],
        keyboardScrolling: false,
        autoScrolling: true,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        scrollOverflow: true,
        controlArrows: false
});

$('.gallery-link').on('click','a',function(){

      var url = "directory/gallery_ajax.php";
      var postid = $(this).attr('data-post');

      $('.loading').addClass('active');

          $.ajax({
             type : 'post',
             url  : url,
             data : {
                    action : 'user_clicked',
                    postid : postid
             },
             success : function( response ) {

                $('.ajax_content').html('<div class="content" id="gallery-container"><div class="isotope">'+response+'</div></div>');
                var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
                       itemSelector: '.item',
                       masonry: {
                         columnWidth: 160,
                         isFitWidth: true
                           }
                    });
                    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
                         $('.loading').removeClass('active');
                         $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(3,0);
                         $container.isotope( 'layout' );
                    });
             },
             error: function( message ){
                     console.log(message);
             }
          });
            return false;
});
```

Comment: "$('.ajax_content').html " in yor response function is content with scroll html?

Comment: yes it contains about 50 images, the scroll should applied on the whole page (section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling "$('.ajax_content').htm" inside your response function you need to initialise scroll plugin again, because you changed dom and plugin must be reinitialized to compute new page dimensions

Comment: the problem with fullpage.js approach not detect if the page has scroll or not, because the page (section) with content needs scroll, the .slimScrollDiv should wrap the content, but here in my case, that class not appear until I resize the browser !

Comment: I followed up all steps and updated the latest version of fullpage.js and slimScroll included with package but nothing changed ! :\ .. is there any way to resize the window using jQuery instantly just to display the scroll according to resize action !

Comment: I found answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986136/fullpage-js-will-only-scrolloverflow-after-window-resize

Comment: Thank you very much you saved me ! Finally .. (reBuild) works similar to resize again .. thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
```

Document [Link](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs)